# SharePoint - Couldn't delete a file from document library

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepointadmin

I am trying to delete a file from a document library in sharepoint. The file was created by another user and while deleting I get an error "The file is locked for shared use by username". Neither me(Admin) nor the user see the document under "Manage files that have no checked in version" which means all the files are checked out. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Take ownership of the documents so you can check them in.  https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3708/taking-control-of-checked-out-documents-in-sharepoint/

Comment: @RickS I do not see any documents listed to take ownership!

Comment: You clicked "Manage Checked Out Files" and you don't see anything?

Comment: @RickS Yes I don't see anything

Comment: In that case I don't know.  This site is more for programming questions than SharePoint admin support.  You might want to try another forum for your question. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to delete the file when I went to Site Settings -> Content and structure and navigate to the file and delete it.